# Possible to order an SQL query that matches with a REGEX by the number of matches found?

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I am using a sql query such as `WHERE name REGEXP '[[:<:]]something[[:>:]]'`.

Now this all works great but my results are not ordered by number of matches found which is what I am looking for. Any ideas on how to go about doing this or if it is even possible?

Thanks

Full Query is

```
    SELECT `Item`.`id`, `Item`.`name`, `Item`.`short_bio`
    FROM `items` AS `Item`
    WHERE ((`Item`.`name` REGEXP '[[:<:]]hello[[:>:]]') OR
           (`Item`.`name` REGEXP '[[:<:]]world[[:>:]]')
```

Now this query is generated based on user input, each space breaks the thing into a different part that is searched for. I would like to order the results based on the number of matches of all parts, this way the most relevant results are on the top.

Comment: You should provide your complete query if you want precise help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an UDF some time ago to do this. I'm really sorry I can't cite the source though.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `substrCount`(s VARCHAR(255), ss VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS tinyint(3) unsigned
    READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
    DECLARE count TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED;
    DECLARE offset TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET s = NULL;

    SET count = 0;
    SET offset = 1;

    REPEAT
        IF NOT ISNULL(s) AND offset > 0 THEN
            SET offset = LOCATE(ss, s, offset);
            IF offset > 0 THEN
                SET count = count + 1;
                SET offset = offset + 1;
            END IF;
        END IF;
    UNTIL ISNULL(s) OR offset = 0 END REPEAT;

    RETURN count;
END

DELIMITER ;
```

There's also a nifty solution found [here](http://nostylesheets.com/2009/07/17/mysql-substr-count/).

Comment: That nifty solution you posted a link for worked perfectly thanks a bunch.

Comment: Also if your would like to rank them as using that function the replace call is case sensitive. Use this user made function to rank matches without case http://forge.mysql.com/tools/tool.php?id=132.

Comment: @bobbake4 thanks for the feedback. I noticed the other solution is about 10 times faster than the UDF I posted.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this (don't know mysql, so it may need tweaking):

```
SELECT `Item`.`id`, `Item`.`name`, `Item`.`short_bio`
FROM `items` AS `Item`
WHERE ((`Item`.`name` REGEXP '[[:<:]]hello[[:>:]]') OR
       (`Item`.`name` REGEXP '[[:<:]]world[[:>:]]')
ORDER BY (`Item`.`name` REGEXP '[[:<:]]hello[[:>:]]') +
         (`Item`.`name` REGEXP '[[:<:]]world[[:>:]]') DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex matching operators in MySQL return either 1 or 0 depending on whether the match was found or not respectively (or null if either a pattern or string is null). No information about number of matches is available, so sorting is not possible either.